# Fiscal Year - Grab a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to grab a list of all the fiscal years...E.g From November-October. I'm not sure if this is the correct solution:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR([date received]) AS [YEAR]  
    FROM [inventory]  
UNION ALL  
  SELECT  MAX(YEAR([date received])) + 1 AS [YEAR]  
    FROM [inventory]  
ORDER BY YEAR DESC  
GO
```

Comment: Some information would help - what database (incl. version), sample data and expected output, what data type the `[date received]` column is...

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Column is date type

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks good.  Depending on the data, you might include the first calendar year, which may not have data associated with it as a fiscal year.  For example, if your first date is December 1, 2009, your first fiscal year is 2010.  Your solution will include 2009.

Here's a query that may work for you

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DATEADD(mm, 2, [date received])) as [FISCAL_YEAR]
FROM [inventory]
ORDER BY [FISCAL_YEAR]
```

It gets the year value after shifting by 2 months (November becomes January).